# Are there Hindu-specific rules/norms for the status of women?

Tags: women, gender

I'm not interested in the modern status of women in Hinduism practitioners, instead I'd like to know what the Hindu doctrine says about it. For example, for religions like Christianity there are certain norms dictated by their bible such as:

> But I would have you know, that the head of every man is Christ; and the head of the woman is the man; and the head of Christ is God. - See more at: http://www.project-reason.org/scripture_project/The_Bible:1_Corinthians_11/#3

Wether or not modern Christians enforce such norm is not relevant to this question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21771/discussion-on-question-by-pgpb-padilla-are-there-hindu-specific-rules-norms-for).

Answer (score 1):

Why single out women? There are norms for both men and women. Like all other countries, the norms are mostly based on custom and local superstition and not religion. The Laws of Manu give some guidance as to the norms for men and women. The Vedas, Brahmanas and Upanishads also give guidance as to what an individual's (man and woman) norms should be throughout life. Especially the 4 stages.

For those who want to pursue a worldly life, the Vedas give directions to both men and women. As a general saying for women, women are told to "Be Sita".

Comment: _Why single out women?_ Because that's what I want to know. I could have asked the same about men but I'm not interested in that question right now.

Answer (score 1):

Before I can go forward I will brief out what is a Women in Hinduism is.

**Female** : According to Hinduism, female is the purest form of Nature, If you delve into deep, hinduism states the Supreme Being divided himself into two parts Prakruti ( Nature or Matter ) and Purusha ( I might call it Anti-Matter, but there are no real theories related to that ), As female contains both parts of Nature, meaning the XX chromosome, where X-chromosome depicts Prakruti and Y-chromosome depicts Purusha, its complete, therefore stated as pure in Hinduism.

**Women** : The human form of this Female entity is woman. As I stated, women are considered as purest form of nature, they are termed as Sati ( Pure ) in Hinduism, they are the regenerator of new lives, and take carer of the existing ones. Women don't need males as much as males need them, because males are not as pure and they seek purity or completeness through woman, and this can also be the reason behind the high number of bisexual females to be found.

**Status of Women** : In Hinduism, the status of woman is considered slightly higher than males. Actually Hinduism doesn't differentiates between both much, but because of the purity of woman and the ability of her to give birth makes it more important and higher than men.

Comment: Could you please add some references? BTW, is there any mention of chromosome s in Hinduism? Isn't that too recent a discovery to be mentioned?

Comment: @pgpb.padilla, you are right, no chromosome mentioned anywhere, I am just trying to relate the scientific norms to the vedic one, as all the vedic literatue is more symbolism type, they might have tried to explain the chromatic theory by purush and prakruti. And the reference is to make the statements more clear even viewed from scientific point.